# Вьюха [прозрачный фон на iOS 7]

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, view

Ребят, подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать вьюху прозрачной, и что бы сзади неё было видно картинку рабочего стола?

[Как тут на 1 рисунке](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82+%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.52434380,d.bGE,pv.xjs.s.en_US.RJfod4swqLE.O&biw=1183&bih=669&dpr=1&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=ru&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=h4tAUvKZAcmp4gS5_YDQAw#hl=ru&q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%85%D0%B0+%D0%BD%D0%B0+ios7&tbm=isch&um=1&facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=IhlJtxRZrR_T6M%3A%3B6onKLdaEL7LYkM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fslon.ru%252Fupload%252Fiblock%252F4a1%252Fios2.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fvlasti.net%252Fnews%252F168153%3B675%3B380)

Comment: Увы никак не сделать чтоб было видно рабочий стол...

Comment: @leonid3452, Меня тоже не давно этот вопрос интересовал, всё что нашёл толковое, так это вот: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041669/creating-a-blurring-overlay-view/17041983#17041983 но ещё не занимался/не пробовал.

Answer (score 1):

Как уже заметили коллеги с фоном рабочего стола не получится. Эффект размытости можно сделать  [так](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JIdcYbAd-NI). Используется библиотека Брэда Ларсона [`GPUImage`](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage). Работает на любых версиях `iOS`.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то это невозможно.

Прозрачная вьюха:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: А если зайти с другой стороны, как получить рисунок рабочего стола, и использовать его в приложении + эффект размытости?